# Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found

Tags: guzzle

A plugin that is using a Guzzle request is now throwing an exception that the class cannot be found.

I'm running Craft CMS 2.6.3000. Where is Guzzle being pulled from? I can see it within `craft/app/vendor/guzzle` and also within `plugins/oauth/vendor` but for some reason this plugin cannot cannot use this class anymore.

It is being referenced as `$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();`

Why can't the class be used?

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick guess, but here is what I have on a project I am working on.

```
$client = new \Guzzle\Http\Client();
$request = $client->get($url);
```

**yours**

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
```

**mine**

```
$client = new \Guzzle\Http\Client();
```

I have `\Http\Client` - maybe you are just missing the slash?

Comment: What's weird though is its been working like this for a while. Maybe a plugin update has caused this, I'm not sure.

Comment: I get `Call to undefined method Guzzle\Http\Client::request()` when using that version for $client.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the class to be used should be:

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

without the first back slash

Comment: This should be posted as comment on the accepted answer, which includes the bulk of this information—but may contain syntactic issues for some environments.